# in C# build oracle command using two conditions

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to pass two user inputs in the window form text box 3, and text box 4 to build a oracle command containing two where conditions.  I don't know how to do it. below is my code, and it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
private void result(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleParameter runNum = new OracleParameter();
        OracleParameter studyID = new OracleParameter();
        runNum.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
        runNum.Value = textBox3.Text;
        studyID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
        studyID.Value = textBox4.Text;

        try
        {

            string oradb = "Data Source=("");User Id="";Password="";";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandText = @"select
                                  *

                                WHERE
                                  condition1 = :study
                                  AND condition2 = :run
                                  ";

            DataTable results = new DataTable();
            cmd = new OracleCommand(cmd.CommandText, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("run", runNum));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("study", studyID));

            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;
            OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(results);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First try your SQL in SQL*Plus or other app that will execute SQL.  You need a FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions: 1) Instead of hiding the error, you could help yourself a bit by catching Exception and outputting its Message property. 2) The query is missing a table. It should start out "select * from *some_table*"... 3) The query makes it look like "condition1" and "condition2" are fields in the table. More likely there are some fields in the table called something like "run" and "study". So you would want "where run = :run and study = :study". 4) Try using a program like SQL Developer (free) to connect to your database and experiment with designing your query to return what you want before incorporating it into your C# program.

Comment: I figure out the problem, my code will work if my oracle comment text is selected from 1 table.

Comment: my code will not work, if my oracle needs to join 7 tables

Answer (score 0):

You code has several issues:

1. `Data Source=("")`: The brackets are not required. However, I don't know whether they cause an exception or if they are optional
2. `cmd.CommandText`: You don't specify any table, `FROM ...` is missing
3. `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("run", runNum));`: Redundant code, simply use `cmd.Parameters.Add("run", runNum);` which should do the same.
4. Same for `cmd = new OracleCommand(cmd.CommandText, conn);`: Redundant, just skip it.
5. What is the purpose of `OracleCommandBuilder builder`? You don't use it anywhere.
6. Use `catch ( Exception err ) { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }` to see the real error.